# Upgrade postgres version from 14 to 15 un kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, psql

Can someone guide me about how to perform a postgres upgrade from 14 to 15 running in a kubernetes? I couldnt find elaborated instrctions anywere

Comment: Dump/restore. Other than that, you'd have to build a special container for `pg_upgrade`. Or you use logical replication, which is the most complicated way.